# Integrating multiple models into one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to build a car dealership web app and I want to optimize testing by combining models into one view. Specifically, the main page is a dropdown list where the user enters his postal code and a car brand (toyota, ford, etc.). I want this to route to /dealerships/search.html.erb. What I want to show on this page is Dealership location, phone number and a link to the dealership home page. All car brands have the same attributes and I want to have one view, where the dealership table is filled with (id: 1 name: toyota, id:2, name: ford, etc.) and each of the toyota table, ford table have a dealership_id attribute. I'm still very confused as to how to implement this. I would really appreciate all suggestions and guidance in the right direction. Also, is this advisable, and is there a way to not have so many controllers and so many models at all. I just want to have the one aggregated view and multiple tables that can be called upon depending on user selection.

Comment: you should use shared partial files and use jquery or ajax to do your actions in the page.

Comment: do you hear about 'nested_form' gem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is possible but not advisable. Rails is based on MVC and you should do logically different tasks in different actions and according to design in different controllers if required. I understand that in beginning it feels like a lot of work but believe me once you start understanding the whole thing it would be more easy to handle and to work with. If you put all the things at once place it will become tough to manage in future.

As far as your projected need are concerned you can make different controllers and actions and call them in the required view where ever wanted. Rails give exception support for thus type of calling and it will all run good and in the right way. I would suggest you to develop this in the suggested way.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is because the models of all 10 car brands have the exact same attributes and they should perform exactly the same way (therefore the same logic and actions). What Im wondering is sort of whether I can have a dealership model that has multiple tables within it, each with the same attributes and the dropdownlist links to a view where the tablename is a variable as well as the attribute per table

Comment: @Borat.sagdiyev See I think you are confusing a little with the concept of models and controllers. For different tables you have to make different models not controllers. The amount of data saved will be almost same anyways so if you insist on making one model take one table and you can have a column for the car brand also in that table and when you want the drop-down list to display the details related to a particular model you can just make a query like `model_name.all.where(:brand => "brand_name")`.

Comment: So this way you can use the same methods inside the model for all the data and retrieving will also be very easy for each brand. I hope I answered you, if you have some confusion please ask.